# Why are Export/Import Script, Edit, Debug greyed out from context menu of many tools in ArcToolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arctoolbox

Most of the options of Export/Import Script, Edit, Debug are greyed out on the ArcTools as shown below, did anyone have similar problem? Know why and what needs to be invoked?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

[image]

Comment: they are compiled I believe. You can't edit those. They are likely in dll files.

Comment: They don't let you mess with the built in gp tools and toolboxes.  Those grayed out options are for tools, script tools, and models you create in your own gp toolboxes.

Comment: @jbchurchill and John It would be good to combine both of these comments into one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the tools in the toolbox cannot be edited. My understanding is that they are compiled (like dll libraries). If you want to look under the hood look for the script symbol or model symbol (both shown in this screenshot) instead of the hammer symbol. The samples in the help menu are likely a better place to start since the tools in the toolbox can be somewhat complicated but Good Luck with this. You may find some answers if you are beyond the beginning stages.

[image: screenshot showing tools that CAN be edited]

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on a model in ArcToolbox and the export script is still grayed out, you should still be able to export to a script by choosing `Model > Export > To Python Script`